# Transfer learning without pretrained weights

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I would like to **use a deep learning architecture** available on Keras([resnet50](https://keras.io/api/applications/resnet/#resnet50-function)), **add a few layers**, and **train the entire ensure model on my data without any pretrained weights while making all layers trainable.**

I am new to transfer learning and am following this [Keras link](https://keras.io/guides/transfer_learning/) and a few other resources.

I am attaching the code that I am using in the below code block.

**What should I do differently to make sure that all layers are trained from scratch on my data without any pretrained weights?**

```
pre_trained_model = ResNet50(input_shape = (150, 150, 3), 
                                include_top = False, )

# Make all the layers in the pre-trained model trainable (unfrozen.)
for layer in pre_trained_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = True 


last_layer = pre_trained_model.get_layer('conv5_block3_3_bn')
last_output = last_layer.output 

x = layers.Flatten()(last_output)
x = layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)                  
x = layers.Dense(3, activation='relu')(x)           

model = Model( pre_trained_model.input, x) 

model.compile(optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(
                          learning_rate=0.01), 
              loss = "mean_squared_error",
              metrics = ["mse"])
```

Comment: If you're not using pre-trained weights, you're not doing transfer learning. You're just reusing an architecture.

Answer (score 2):

By default, Keras models available in the `keras.applications` module come with weights pretrained on the imagenet dataset. Simply pass `None` to the `weights` argument to get a model initialized with random weights.

```
pre_trained_model = ResNet50(input_shape = (150, 150, 3), 
                            include_top = False, weights=None)
```

You can read more in the documentation: [Keras Applications / ResNet and ResNetV2](https://keras.io/api/applications/resnet/#resnet50-function) :

> Arguments
>
> - weights: one of None (random initialization), 'imagenet' (pre-training on ImageNet), or the path to the weights file to be loaded.